# find a record by value field

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have a custom object `Object` with field `Status`. And there is a list of those objects: `Obj1`, `Obj2`, `Obj3`, ...
In apex class I create:

```
list <Object> obj = [SELECT id, Status__c FROM Object__c];
```

I need to know if there an objects with `Status == 'Pending'` and if Yes - do some action.

Comment: You should start by reading this Trailhead [tutorial](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_database/units/apex_database_soql).

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the SOQL and add `where clause` to check the condition.

To just know if records exist, use `count()`

```
Integer countOfRecords = [SELECT count() FROM Object__c WHERE Status__c = 'Pending'];
if(countOfRecords > 0){
 //perform the action
}
```

If you want to do some processing on the records, then use fetch the data from the SOQL

```
list <Object> obj = [SELECT Id, Status__c FROM Object__c WHERE Status__c = 'Pending'];
if(obj.size() > 0){
 //perform the action
}
```

Refer [SOQL in Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm).

Comment: SOQL will always return an instantiated list, so you do not need the null check.

Comment: It will return null if no records are found. So, we need to do a null check

Comment: No, it will return an empty list.  And if what you were saying were true, you wouldn't need to check the size.

Comment: Good point, So, I can only check the size and avoid two checks.